# How to login to AWS Console using Access Key, Secret Key and Session token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have cognito user pool and identity pool and a application where i have integrated all these things and doing signup and signin and getting temporary credentials like Access Key, Secret Key and Session token. I want to create a button in my application, so that after successful signin, one button will appear to open AWS console and that user will be able to access AWS Services like S3.

I got this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html) which can be used to create URL which i can put behind my button but how to implement this, I am trying with Java but its not working

```
 GetFederationTokenRequest getFederationTokenRequest = 
  new GetFederationTokenRequest();
getFederationTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(1800);
getFederationTokenRequestet.getName("UserName");

// A sample policy for accessing Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) in the console.

String policy = "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":\"sns:*\"," +
  "\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}";

getFederationTokenRequest.setPolicy(policy);
```

It says multiple marker at this line. SetDurationSeconds, SetName, SetPolicy have this error

Comment: Please, provide the exact errors you get. Preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate AWS console URL from the temporary credentials by retrieving a SigninToken from the https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation endpoint.

First, you need to create a JSON object with the AWS temporary credentials:

```
{
  "sessionId": "<aws access key id>",
  "sessionKey": "<aws secret access key>",
  "sessionToken": "<aws session token>"
}
```

Use that JSON as a value for "Session" parameter in the following URL

`https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation?Action=getSigninToken&Session=<the JSON object>`

The JSON response will look like:

```
{
  "SigninToken":"VsPfcblaC....."
}
```

Use the SigninToken value in the following URL. It will open the console:

`https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation?Action=login&Destination=https://console.aws.amazon.com/&SigninToken=<SigninToken>`

The "Destination" value can be a specific service URL like EC2 or S3

I created a sample implementation here: https://gist.github.com/janaz/80b1f6054a044ce78cbf5abae7288b50

Comment: thanks for your efforts, I am trying to integrate your Node JS code in mine HTML Code but somewhere it is not working,  If you know how to integrate both codes, I tried converting in Browserfiy but not working out here is my code, github.com/sparshgoyal024/TestAWS/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the correct IAM Roles with permissions to access your AWS resources (S3, Console, etc.) Read more details in [Cognito Developer Guide - IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html).

About your Java Code, it looks like the example in the link provided is not ready to use as "copy & paste". Also, it depends on the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) that you need to import into your project.

Make sure to paste the code below the imports into the right code block. ***Multiple markers*** errors appear when you're trying to insert statements directly into a class, rather than having them in a constructor, method, initializer, etc.